# How to determine what kind of conic section in the affine plane?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

So, I've been struggling a bit with understanding this problem.
Let $P^2$ be the real projective plane with homogenous coordinates $(x_0:x_1:x_2)$

Let $\cal{C}$ be the line given by $$x_0^2 + 2x_0x_1+3x_1x_2-3(x_2^2)=0$$

Determine the conic section so that $\cal{C}$ is in the affine plane, where $x_1\neq x_2.$

I found that there are two points where $x_1-x_2=0$ and $\cal{C}$ coincide, namely $x_0=x_1 \; \text{and}\; x_0=-x_1,$ and that when $x_2\neq 0,$ $\cal{C}$ is not degenerated.
What I dont understand is how we can know that the conic section in the affine plane will be a hyperbola.
The way this was explained to me is because we know that there are two points that are in the intersection with $x_2=x_1,$ although I dont see why it follows that it is a hyperbola. Similarly, how would it look if it were say, a circle.

Comment: You can also dehomogenize by setting $x_1-x_2=1$ or $x_1=x_2+1$ in $x_0^2 + 2x_0x_1+3x_1x_2-3(x_2^2)=0$ to get $2x_0x_2+3x_2+x_0^2+2x_0=0$, now an  equation in two variables easily checked to be a hyperbola. Also, a quick google search gave this [link](https://blogs.adelaide.edu.au/maths-learning/2016/07/14/the-line-at-infinity-conics/) to address your real question.

Comment: Note that circles can’t be distinguished from other ellipses until you impose a Euclidean geometry on the affine plane.